# In vim, why is it :-1j to join with the line above?

Tags: vim

In vim, why is it `:-1j` to join with the line above?

e.g. `:g/^ /-1j` to join all lines that start with a space.

The commands are easier to remember when you understand how they come about and in this case I had expected `:g/^ /-1J`

`-1` move to move to the line above and `J` to join with line below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a normal command on the command-line *as is*.

In `:g/^ /-1j`, `j` is the abbreviation of `:join`: you go up one line (`-1`, it could be `-`) and you execute `:join`.

In `:g/^ /-1J`, `J` means nothing to Vim: you are using a normal mode command out of its context so, basically, it does nothing after `-1` except echoing a clear error message.

Vim expects an Ex command, there, not a normal mode command.

Your confusion may come from the fact that the colon is needed only once so you are not recognizing Ex commands. If we added a couple of colons, the full command would probably make more sense to you:

```
:g/^ /:-1:j
```

To use normal mode commands on the command-line, use `:norm`:

```
:g/^ /-1norm J
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of commands in `vi`.  There are the commands that can be invoked directly from command-mode anywhere in the file (I'm not sure if there's a specific name for these kinds of commands), and there are commands that come from `ex` that specifically operate on lines (not on characters) and require a `:` character to invoke them.

Typically, only the `ex` commands can be used with the `:g` command.